# Controlling the height of table lines

Tags: tables

I'm trying to make a signature line. I can't think of anything but using the tabular environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,icelandic]{report}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[b]                                % force to the bottom.
\begin{flushright}                              % Flush table to right.
\begin{tabular}{l}                              % Text aligning to left.
    \hspace{-6pt}City, Date        \\           % Aligning the text with the signature line.
                                   \\ \hline    % Making the signature line. (No Text)
    \hspace{-6pt}My full name under the line.   % My full name written here.
\end{tabular} 
\end{flushright}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This works just like I wanted it to do... But my name under the signature line is so close to the line and I need to offset it. I would also like to get more gap from the signature line to to the city/date text. - I have been trying to use \vspace{pt} but it seems like it's not the right one.

Any ideas?[image]

Comment: use `@{}l@{}` instead of `\hspace{-6pt}` and use `array` package and `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}` to get extra padding to the rows

Comment: Thank you David. But what if I don't want to change the extra row height for all the document. Just a single row?

Comment: If you put it inside the flushright it will just affect that tabular not the whole document, it will affect both lines though. If you really don't want that use `\rule{0pt}{25pt}` (or whatever height you need) in your second row to put a zero width rule to force the row height

Comment: You can also use `\\[<height>]` on individual rows. `\\[2pt]` for example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps is a bit of an hacky solution, I used array to get rid of the unwanted space, as DavidCarlisle suggested; then I inserted an extra row break with a negative spacing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,icelandic]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[b]                                % force to the bottom.
\begin{flushright}                              % Flush table to right.
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}                              % Text aligning to left.
City, Date        \\         % Aligning the text with the signature line.
                                      \\ \hline\\[-2ex] % Making the signature line. (No Text)
My full name under the line.   % My full name written here.
\end{tabular} 
\end{flushright}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to shift one `\vbox` right:

```
\hfill\vbox{\hsize=.4\hsize \parindent=0pt
   City, Date
   \vskip 1cm
   \hrule
   \medskip
   My full name under the line.
}
```